# Can't translate child theme

Tags: translation

Using last version of Wordpress, I am stuck here. I can't translate my theme, some of the strings remain in english (I want french).

I use Poedit and generated the .mo file.

I pasted it in :

```
/themes/homeland-child/languages/fr_FR.mo
```

I checked in it, I find my translated strings.

`homeland-child` is my theme, it's a child from `homeland` theme.

But, strings are still in English on the website.

For example `Leave a comment` remains in English on the site.

My site is in french, dunno if there is a kind of cache ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found on a blog this solution, paste in functions.php of your child theme :

```
function child_theme_slug_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'parent-theme-domain', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_slug_setup' );
```

Comment: This code shows your child theme loading the parent theme's text domain. The parent should load its text domain. The child should load its text domain. They are separate and not inherited.

Comment: Some tips here: https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/child-themes

Comment: I don't understand ? My code makes the child theme to load the language file located in the child theme, and I keep the parent domain, since I want to override all translations. I will not recreate a text domain only for the child, the aim here is to override (the aim of a child theme for me)

Comment: You are free to do it any way you like if it works for you, but my recommendation is in that link. My recommendation is based on seeing hundreds of people very confused about how localization works in child themes. Your code suggestion may work for you, but spreads poor advice that others may follow.